# Seagate Backup Plus Mac reformatted to NTFS don't mount on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ntfs, hfs

I have a Seagate Backup Plus Mac drive that, as the name implies, came with the HFS format for Mac. I reformatted it to NTFS to be compatible with a Windows PC (I was not working with Mac at the time). I tried recently to read the disk on a Mac, but unlike other NTFS disks (which can be read, albeit don't written), it don't mount at all. I also tested at other computers and my results are:

- At some Linux version, it read fine out of the box
- At a Windows PC it don't read by default, but it reads when I install a HFS driver (despite the drive itself still being recognized as NTFS when is mounted)

Is there any way it can be read on Mac as it is, or even, reformat the disk erasing its data so it can be HFS again?

Answer (score 1):

You can surely wipe it using Disk Utility and choose ExFAT or HFS+ or partition and use both. If cross platform is your goal, I would see if ExFAT works for your needs.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/erase-a-volume-dskutl14079/mac

For any of the choices above, use GPT the GUID Partition Scheme.